# unauthorize when adding Visual Studio Team Services workspace to intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tfs, azure-devops

I'm getting a unauthorized error when adding a workspace in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) to Intellij 15. The account I'm using is the owner of the workspace and I'm using the alternative connection method which is enabled in Team Services. My password and everything is correct so what am I doing wrong?

Here is a peek of what I'm entering:

```
Address: https://myname.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyProject/
Auth: Alternate
Username: myname
Domain: 
Password: *******
```

Comment: You typically authorize against the collection, not the project. Try `https://myname.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/` instead.

Comment: Getting the same problem when I try that

Comment: What is the detailed error message you get?

Comment: The error I'm getting is just Unauthorized. I'm using my primary account. Could there be some problem with VS Online and the intellij TFS plugin?

Comment: @MarioDennis The primary account and alternative password?

Comment: Do I need a alternative password? I'm using the password for the primary account.

Comment: @MarioDennis When you enable the alternative authenticate, you should have to set a alternative password. You can use either primary account or secondary account. But you must use the alternative password you entered.

Comment: Ok I was not prompted to enter an alternative password when I enabled it. Going to check it again

Comment: Ok, that fixed my problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

The address does not need to include "Project" name in it, so just use:

```
https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/
```

And you need to double check to make sure that the address and credential you entered is correct.

If you get "Unauthorized" error message, this is usually caused by the incorrect username you entered.

If you get "Transport error:401 Error:Unauthorized", the password you entered may incorrect.

You can also try to connect with the "User name (primary)" when you enable VSTS alternate authentication credentials.